# LINQ with EF, cannot convert string to List<string>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'd like to return 4 columns from address table in entity framework. However it errors out at "address = addressData.toString();" saying cannot implicitly convert type string to System.Collection.Generic.List

```
[WebMethod]
    public List<string> getAddressSearchSimple(string addressInput)
    {

        List<string> address = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            using (GISAddressEntities database = new GISAddressEntities())
            {
                var addressData = (from table in database.view_COBADDRESS
                                   where table.ADD_FULL.Contains(addressInput)
                                   select new { table.ADD_FULL, table.POSTALCITY, table.STATE, table.ZIP5});
                address = addressData.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return address;
    }
```

Comment: It is not clear what your expected output is. Do you want each address in the list to be converted to a string?

Comment: If I type "123 Main" then rows that contains this address will return like 123 Main St, 1234 Main, 123 Main st, etc' In SQL there many other columns but I just want to see only 4 columns including address, city, state, zip.

Comment: That's what I figured, however you are returning an object not a string from your LINQ Select. you need to convert that to a string - see the answers posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I think this may be what you are looking for:

```
address = addressData.ToList().Select(addr => string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", addr.ADD_FULL, addr.POSTALCITY, 
           addr.STATE, addr.ZIP5)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

address is a List of string, so you cannot set any object as ToString().

if addressData should be a List of Strings to try this:

```
var addressData = (from table in database.view_COBADDRESS
               where table.ADD_FULL.Contains(addressInput)
               select new { table.ADD_FULL, table.POSTALCITY, 
               table.STATE, table.ZIP5}).ToList();
```

Comment: I added "table.ZIP5}).ToString()).ToList(); There is no programming error but no value returns.

Comment: I can return only one column fine like this. "select table.ADD_FULL); but hard time to return multiple columns in LINQ

Comment: Try the followin:

select new {ADD_FULL= table.ADD_FULL, POSTALCITY = table.POSTALCITY,....}

Answer (score 0):

You should call the ToList() method instead of ToString() to create a List. You should also select strings from your query in order to get a `List<string>`. Try this:

```
public List<string> getAddressSearchSimple(string addressInput)
{

    List<string> address = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        using (GISAddressEntities database = new GISAddressEntities())
        {
            var addressData = (from table in database.view_COBADDRESS
                               where table.ADD_FULL.Contains(addressInput)
                               select new { table.ADD_FULL, table.POSTALCITY, table.STATE, table.ZIP5 });

            address = addressData.Select(x => string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", x.ADD_FULL, x.POSTALCITY, x.STATE, x.ZIP5))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    return address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `addressData` is not a list of strings - it is a list of a temporary class that contains the 4 fields in your `select`. It would work if you modified the `select` to get only one field.

However, as you say you want the four fields, I suggest you create a new class, called maybe `AddressDetails`, with a property for each field. Then you can simply write:

```
AddressDetails data = (from table in database.view_COBADDRESS
                               where table.ADD_FULL.Contains(addressInput)
                               select new { table.ADD_FULL, table.POSTALCITY, table.STATE, table.ZIP5 });
return data;
```

Having changed the return type of the method to match.